# How to convert single Java file to MVC design?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, tic-tac-toe

I have used Java to write the program for `3 X 3` TicTacToe but i want to know how can Separate single file to `mvc` pattern design whithout using java swing.
Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {
   static final int X = 1;
   static final int O = -1;
   
    public static void printBoard( int [][] matrix ){
      
      for( int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ){
         for( int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++ ){
            // Uses the "global" constants to print out appropriate letter.
            if( matrix[row][col] == X )
               System.out.print("X ");
            else if(matrix[row][col] == O )
               System.out.print("O ");
            else 
               System.out.print(". ");
          }
          // Goes to new line after printing each row
          System.out.println("");
       }
   }

   //hasWon returns true if there was a win or a cat game.
   public static boolean hasWon( int [][] matrix ){
      //Variable holds the "result" of hasWon. True if a winner was found.
      boolean retVal = false;
      
      //Check for horizontal win
      for( int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ){
         int sum = 0;
         for( int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++ ){
            sum += matrix[row][col];
         }
         //Check to see if the sum of that row was 3 or -3, a win...
         if( sum == 3 ){
            System.out.println("X wins.");
            retVal = true;
         } else if ( sum == -3 ) {
            System.out.println("O wins.");
            retVal = true;
         }
      }
      
      //Check for vertical win
      for( int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++ ){
         int sum = 0;
         for( int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ){
            sum += matrix[row][col];
         }
         //Check to see if the sum of that column was 3 or -3, a win...
         if( sum == 3 ){
            System.out.println("X wins.");
            retVal = true;
         } else if ( sum == -3 ) {
            System.out.println("O wins.");
            retVal = true;
         }
      }
      
      //Check for diagonal win
      if( (matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][2]) == 3 ){
         System.out.println("X wins.");
         retVal = true;
      } else if ( (matrix[0][0] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][2]) == -3 ) {
         System.out.println("O wins.");
         retVal = true;
      }
      if( (matrix[0][2] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][0]) == 3 ){
         System.out.println("X wins.");
         retVal = true;
      } else if ( (matrix[0][2] + matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][0]) == -3 ) {
         System.out.println("O wins.");
         retVal = true;
      }
      
      //Check for cat game
      boolean foundSpace = false;
      for( int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++ ){
         for( int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++ ){
            if( matrix[row][col] == 0 ) 
               foundSpace = true;
         }
      }
      if( foundSpace == false ){
         System.out.println("Ends in tie.");
         retVal = true;
      }
      
      return retVal;
   }
   
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      //A 3x3 array stored as integers. X will be 1. O will be -1.
      int [][] board = new int[3][3];
      
      while( hasWon(board) == false){
         
         //Get the X player input and make the change if not taken.
         System.out.print("X, enter row: ");
         int row = input.nextInt();
         System.out.print("X, enter column: ");
         int col = input.nextInt();
         if( board[row][col] == 0 )
            board[row][col] = X;
            
         printBoard(board);
         
         //Check to see if X's move won the game. If so, break out of game loop
         if( hasWon(board) == true )
            break;
         
         //Get the O player input and make the change if not taken.
         System.out.print("O, enter row: ");
         row = input.nextInt();
         System.out.print("O, enter column: ");
         col = input.nextInt();
         if( board[row][col] == 0 )
            board[row][col] = O;
         
         printBoard(board);
         
      }
      
      System.out.println("Game over.");
   }
}
```

Here what I am trying to learn is how can we divide single java file to model where logic goes, view for console part which work as frontend and controller to connect. I try to look over differnt source but all of them are using JFrame or Java swing but i don't want to use both of those. Is there any way like i can design ?
Thank you.

Comment: The MVC pattern is for UIs, Without a UI you dont need that pattern. Whaat do you like to achieve with using that pattern?

Comment: @JensBaitinger I was curious to divide single .java file to model.java, view.java and controller.java

Comment: One could argue that System.out.print and the use of Scanner could be seen as the View and the 2d array is the Model. Maybe that would be a place to start.

Comment: @JensBaitinger I would argue that every worth while application has a UI of some sort.  A user interface doesn't imply a human interface, just that an interface exists.  System.out and System.in for sure should count as an interface.